# Conditionals with custom variables

Tags: ansible

In my playbook i have tasks that use the hostname of a server and extrapolate data to set location and environment based on that. But some servers have unique names and I'm not sure how to set variables on those. I'd prefer not to use ansible facts since i would like to share the playbook with a team. One way I was thinking is to do what's listed below but i'm running into issues. Could someone please guide me.

```
Create vars_file inventory
---
customservers
  customhostname1:
   env: test
   location: hawaii
  customhostname2:
   env: prod
   location: alaska

In Playbook.

---
task
  tasks:
    - name: set hostname
      shell: echo "customhostname1"
      register: my_hostname

    - name: setting env var
      set_fact:
        env: "{{ item.value.env }}"
      when: my_hostname == "{{ item.key }}"
      with_dict: "{{ customservers }}"

    - name: outputing env var
      debug: 
        msg: the output is {{ env }}

Expected output should be test.
```

Thank you.

Comment: The answer can basically be summarized to `"{{ hostvars['customhostname1'].env }}"`

Answer (score 2):

> In my playbook i have tasks that use the hostname of a server and
> extrapolate data to set location and environment based on that.

Bad Idea.

> But some servers have unique names and I'm not sure how to set variables on those

And that is why.

The second Bad Idea is to have TEST and PROD in the same inventory.  That's just begging for a disaster.  They should be two completely separate inventories, though perhaps under the same parent directory:

```
inventories/
inventories/test/
inventories/test/hosts
inventories/test/host_vars/
inventories/test/host_vars/customhostname1.yml
inventories/prod/
inventories/prod/hosts
inventories/prod/host_vars/
inventories/prod/host_vars/customhostname2.yml
```

So `inventories/prod/hosts` could look like this (I prefer the `ini` format):

```
[customservers]
customhostname2  location=hawaii
```

Or:

```
[customservers]
customhostname2

[customhostname2:vars]
location=hawaii
```

But in any case, DO NOT combine test and prod inventories.

If you still need that `env` variable, you can either put it in `group_vars/all.yml` or right in the `hosts` file like so:

```
[all:vars]
env=prod
```

Comment: Hi @jack,

You have made really great points and gave me a lot to think about. I think the approach about adding variables into inventory is the right one for me. Thank you so much for a great write up.